# Largest text usable variable in MSSQL 2005 Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

What is the largest size text usable variable in a MSSQL Stored Procedure.  I'm seeing that largest size you can use is a varchar(8000).

We can use ntext, text, etc.  So does it require stitching varchars together?

What about if I used a CLR Stored Procedure??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried nvarchar(max)?

Also, please state which version of SQL Server you're using.

Comment: Yeah, but nvarchar(max) is all International.  :-)